# How to interpret the domain and codomain of the function?

Tags: functions

Suppose, I take for $n≥1$ we consider $\cos(nx)$ : $[0,1] \to \Bbb R $

I understand that domain is restricted between $0$ and $1$. Codomain being  $\Bbb R$.

So, is it valid to say $|\cos(nx)| \leq 1 = -1≤\cos(nx)≤1$ . I think this should be right as the range $\in$ codomain which is not restricted, so $-1≤y≤1$. Another way is to visualize a semicircle going through I and IV Quadrant (vertically)

or the domain is restricted $[0,1]$. So, $0≤\cos(nx)≤1$.

also, So every $x$ value from the domain is giving a $y$ from the codomain ( which has to between $-1$ and $+1$ unit ciricle understanding)?

I am still a bit confused. Please if you guys could clarify

Comment: Yes, the domain is restricted to between $0$ and $1$, and we can choose the codomain to be $\mathbb{R}$. I say 'choose' because we could just as well say that the codomain is $\mathbb{C}$, or $[-1,1]$. However, without further information what $n$ could be, it is impossible to say what the range is. For instance, if $n=1$, then the range is $[\cos(1),1]$; if $n=\pi/2$, then the range is $[0,1]$. Finally, you write $|\cos(nx)|\leq 1 = -1 \leq \cos(nx) \leq 1$. This is not a correct use of the equality sign, which should be reversed for saying that two numbers are equal.

Comment: Hey @Joe, thanks for the response. I will go through it

Answer (score 1):

With  n $\geq 4$ and  $n <4$ cases, we can get the answers directly.

**Case I: n $\geq 4$**  range $\to$ $[-1,1]$

To ensure your range to be $[-1,1]$,  need $nx$ to cover at least $\pi$, $nx \geq \pi$, or $n \geq \frac{\pi}{x}$. Since $x$ max is $1$, so as long as  $n \geq \pi$ (or n $\geq 4$), you will have a full range of $[-1,1]$.

**Case II: $n < 4$** range $\to$  $[\cos n,1]$

For $n < 4$ (or $n= 1,2,3$), you can get the range by calculating $\cos 1 (~0.54), \cos 2 (~ -0.42)$ and $\cos 3(~=0.99)$  and replace $\cos n$ with these values directly: $[\cos n,1] $

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever value $nx$ may take, $\cos(nx)$ always lies between $-1$ and $1$. In your question, the domain of definition is restricted which is $[0,1]$. But your $f(x)$ can go negative for suitable choice of $n$ and $x$, though the left end of the range interval depends on the value of $n$. for every $n\ge 4$, the range set is $[-1,1]$ because for such $n$, you can always find $x=\pi/n$ which is less than $1$. Also $[-1,1]\subset\Bbb{R}$ and this is an into mapping.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response could you please elaborate a bit more on "into" mapping. Should I understand into as one-to-one?.

Comment: an into mapping is a mapping where the range set is a proper subset of the codomain. if the codomain and the range set  are same sets, then it is called an onto mapping.

Comment: @ManjoyDas: I deleted my last comment because I didn't formulate it properly. What I mean is that if $n=5$, then the range is $[-1,1]$, not $[\cos(5x),1]$ (and not $[\cos(5),1]$ either). It doesn't make sense to say that the range is $[\cos(nx),1]$, because $x$ is a variable.

Comment: @Joe I am not sure how you obtained $-1$. because the op said that $n\ge1$ and $x\in[0,1]$. So the total argument of cos is positive

Comment: @ManjoyDas: Take a look at [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xhvigc9pm8) graph. It is easy to see visually that the range is $[-1,1]$, even though the domain is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Joe yes. for $n=5$ and $x=\pi/5<1$, $\cos(nx)$ goes negative. thanks for pointing that. I missed that aspect.

Comment: @ManjoyDas: No worries. We all make mistakes.